# How to assign a Value taken from the database to a label?

Tags: java

I need to assign a string taken by a query from the database to a Jlabel. I tried many methods but failed. How can i do it?

```
try{
  String sql="SELECT MAX(allocationID) FROM allocation where unit='"+ dept + " ' ";
  pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  String x=  (pst.execute());
}
catch(Exception e){
}
```

Comment: Never concatenate your query parameters directly into your SQL string, this opens up your code for SQL Injections. Use a [PreparedStatement](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_prepared_statement.htm) instead.

Comment: where do you assign value to lable ?

Comment: JLabel is irrelevant here.  You are really just asking how you get a value from a jdbc call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to study the steps to connect to the database in java First [db steps](http://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-connect-to-the-database-in-java)
Get the resultset from the statment by calling `ResultSet rs = pst.execute();`
Iterate through the list of rows by using the resultset object. 
After that assign the value to the JLabel.

Answer (score 0):

You just made several errors in your tiny program, take a look at the code below as an example:

```
    // your way of using prepared statement is wrong.
    // use like this
    String sql="SELECT MAX(allocationID) FROM allocation where unit=?;"; 
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    // assign values to the variables in the query string
    ps.setString(1, dept);

    // execute the query
    ResultSet rst = ps.executeQuery();

    // parse the result set to get the value
    // You'd better do some check here to ensure you get the right result
    rst.next();
    String x = rst.getInt(1) + "";

    ps.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

Have a look at the article if you are interested:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Comment: It worked. Thank you a lot. Can you tell me how to change the value in the label when i select different values from the Combo Box?  Should i try a loop for it?